# How do I make it so when the user inputs 2 values with 'and' in the middle it executes one case?

Tags: java, switch-statement

The user has to input 2 variables at once in order to get the outputted screen. Any help on the code?

```
            switch(cardChoice)
            {
                case 1 && 5:
                  System.out.println("You have matched the :) card! You get 10 Points!");
                  System.out.println("-------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------");
                  System.out.println("|     |  |     |  |     |  |     |  |     |  |     |");
                  System.out.println("|  :) |  |  2  |  |  3  |  |  4  |  |  :) |  |  6  |");
                  System.out.println("|     |  |     |  |     |  |     |  |     |  |     |");
                  System.out.println("-------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------");
                  System.out.println("-------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------");
                  System.out.println("|     |  |     |  |     |  |     |  |     |  |     |");
                  System.out.println("|  7  |  |  8  |  |  9  |  |  10 |  |  11 |  |  12 |");
                  System.out.println("|     |  |     |  |     |  |     |  |     |  |     |");
                  System.out.println("-------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------");
                  cardPoints = cardPoints + 10;
                break;
                default:
                  System.out.println("Invalid Input!");

            }
```

Comment: FYI, I cannot use an if-statement as it is a college project and I have already used an if statement twice which can only be used a few times

Comment: If `cardChoice` is of type `int`, how can it be `1` and `5` at the same time?

Comment: cardChoice is type char and then I have String userInput. Before my switch statement I did:                           
userInput = scan.next();
cardChoice = userInput.charAt(0);

Comment: I just wrote a comment to a now deleted answer that was correct if you wanted to check if one of two cards was selected. Your question is how to check if "both cards were chosen at the same time". I guess we would have to look at how you handle the input of "two variables at the same time" to help how to check if both are correctly set. However, I think something like if (a && b)... Would be the cleanest way

Comment: @Andreas yes, I misunderstood the question and therefore deleted the answer.

Comment: char cardChoice;
String userInput;
int cardPoints = 0; these are my declared variables that are relevant to the code above

Comment: As I said, I'd go for an if statement. In case you really don't want to do that, why don't you make the switch accept a string and make the cases "15" and "51" (if your input has to be with and in between, change the cases or clean the I out as you see fit)? Just to be clear, I don't like that solution myself, but it would work with the constraints you are giving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **must** do it with a `switch`, there a couple of ways you might go about it.  The trick is that `case` labels can only be single values, so you must somehow combine the two inputs into a single value that that can be matched by a `case` label.

If you only need a two-way test (e.g., user choices were either 1 and 5, or  something else), reducing the inputs to a yes/no answer is sufficient.  You could do something like this:

```
    int choice1, choice2;
    System.out.println("Enter the number of your first card choice:");
    choice1 = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the number of your second card choice:");
    choice2 = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    // ...
    switch (choice1 == 1 && choice2 == 5 ? "yes" : "no"){
        case "yes":
             //  RIGHT!
             break;
        default:
             System.out.println("Invlid input!");
    }
```

If it's going to be a true `switch` with multiple possible cases, you'll need to get a bit more creative.  You could, for instance, create a `String` containing the user's choices in a predictable format that you can then match with a `case`.  For example:

```
    int choice1, choice2;
    System.out.println("Enter the number of your first card choice:");
    choice1 = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the number of your second card choice:");
    choice2 = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    // ...
    String userChoice = String.format("%02d,%02d", choice1, choice2);
    switch (userChoice){
        case "01,05":
             //  RIGHT!
             break;
        case "02,04":
             // Another right answer!
             break;
        default:
             System.out.println("Invlid input!");
    }
```

Yet another way would be to combine the user's choices into a single number, in a way that preserves both values.  For example, let's say we know that valid choices for either input will be less than 10.  We could use:

```
    int choice1, choice2;
    System.out.println("Enter the number of your first card choice:");
    choice1 = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the number of your second card choice:");
    choice2 = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    // ...
    switch (choice1 * 10 + choice2){
        case 15:   // User chose 1 and 5
             //  RIGHT!
             break;
        case 24:   // User chose 2 and 4
             // Another right answer!
             break;
        default:
             System.out.println("Invlid input!");
    }
```

Comment: I like your answer and will upvote it, but I have to add that if I was the teacher I would count the first solution you proposed as an if statement, even though it is hidden behind the ternary conditional operator.